# Flutter, fetching google_fonts at runtime via HTTP even in release mode

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

If i'm right, `google_fonts` plugin loads font through `http` during `debug`. Later when our app is ready we have to download the font from the [fonts.google.com](http://fonts.google.com) . and store it in `pubsec.yaml`.

I am developing a flutter application where all the available fonts should be shown to the users. But if i can't fetch it in the runtime, i will have to download every file, which counts over a thousand. It might become difficult as my app size increases and i will have to manually download them all.

So my question is, can i fetch it in the runtime , or is there some other way to achieve it? Hope someone can answer me. Thank You

edit: It ran without problems. The problem was not with google_fonts, my code was not reflecting changes, so i got wrong release apk

Comment: add internet permission in android, google fonts will work fine in release mode

Comment: i added it, but did not work without downloading it and adding it to asset in pubsec.yaml

Comment: It was another error which was not related to google_fonts. The code was not updated so  i got wrong release apk

Answer (score 2):

When you just get that once. this should be work.means your project must not running .you must stop running then `pub get`.